# ABBYY Flexicapture 'Internal Program Error' on repeating group

Tags: ocr, abbyy

Something happened to corrupt an ABBYY FlexiCapture project of mine. In the Document Definition Editor, when I expand a couple of my repeating groups, I get:

```
Internal Program error:
.\DocumentTemplate\TemplateNode.cpp, 626.
```

Then I can click OK and *some* of the children elements will load and some will not. This means I cannot update rules in the ones that don't show up.

Is there a known way to fix this? Right now I'm rebuilding the whole document definition.

I'm using the distributed version of the software.

Answer (score 0):

InternalProgramError is usually some kind of unhanded error, thus reference to the CPP file code line.  I have no information regarding this specific error, unfortunately, but the fact that it worked before and started to produce the error some time after use indicates that the setup was correct but got corrupted at some point.  Otherwise, if you made a change to the template, and started to see that error, undoing that change is the way to go.  Usually it is pretty rare to cause these errors in the template modification in the first place, unless you are doing something noncustomary with the UI, or in scripts.